# How to make it work? fltk-1.3.2

Tags: c++

im aware that this topic is popular but i haven't found similar issue anywhere else :

i've done all steps for instalation and implementation so i'll skip that part.

I get this message :

> 1>d:\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\window.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'FL/Fl.H': No such file or directory
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

in this code :

```
//
// This is example code from Chapter 12.3 "A first example" of
// "Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup
//

#include "stdafx.h"          // get access to our window library
#include "Simple_window.h"   // get access to our graphics library facilities
#include "Graph.h" 
int main()
{
using namespace Graph_lib;   // our graphics facilities are in Graph_lib

Point tl(100,100);           // to become top left  corner of window

Simple_window win(tl,600,400,"Canvas");    // make a simple window

Polygon poly;                // make a shape (a polygon)                      

poly.add(Point(300,200));    // add a point
poly.add(Point(350,100));    // add another point
poly.add(Point(400,200));    // add a third point 

poly.set_color(Color::red);  // adjust properties of poly

win.attach (poly);           // connect poly to the window

win.wait_for_button();       // give control to the display engine
```

}

How to fix?

Comment: Did you miss to set a correct additional include path (`-I`) when compiling?

Comment: /Ic:\fltk-1.3.2 i have this if that's what you mean

Comment: Yes (so you are working on windows, interesting). And the header file in question can be found there using the specified relative path?

Comment: i dragged them into solution window in vs2012 in "Header Files" section if thats what you mean

Comment: You shouldn't copy any header files from external libraries there! That's most likely your problem. Just specify the right include directory, where to find them.

Comment: in properties->configuration->linker->command line i have : c:\fltk-1.3.2\lib\fltk.lib wsock32.lib comctl32.lib  ,its actually the same error if i include those headers or not

Comment: I think you should have s.th. like `/Ic:\fltk-1.3.2\include` for your compiler, the linker hasn't anything to do with this error (it's the preprocessor complaining). Again, check the directory structure where your lib is installed. I don't know anything about that specific stuff.

Comment: /Ic:\fltk-1.3.2\include gives the same error as /Ic:\fltk-1.3.2, matter of fact if i write compile_you_peace_of_s**t = no changes!

Comment: Something very curious - why would windows.h include Fl.h?  Have you created this as a Windows project or console project?  You really don't want to mix the Windows API and the FLTK API.

Comment: I doesn't seem to be really a problem of your library installation. I just noticed, that `windows.h` want's to include this?!? Did you copy more stuff to your project, you shouldn't have copied?

Comment: its console project, and project is just copy/paste, no modifications

Comment: its window.h not windows.h :)

Comment: its header file from Stoustrup's page  [link](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/)

Comment: I think im onto something, by default it was set `#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"` what i needed to modify to `#include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"` depending on where the actuall file is , so all i need to modify is `#include <FL/Fl.H>` but i dont understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

Upper issue is solved by copying from

> \Downloads\fltk-1.3.2-source\fltk-1.3.2

the FL folder (and std_lib_facilities.h if you haven't done that before) to

> \Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\

With that done everything gets linked together.